# Python @patch not working

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to test a method that within it creates an instance of another class, I am attempting to mock the creation of the inner class... That is not working for me. I tried replicating the problem to a simplified case - and still no go. Here is the simplified case:

I have a directory named `pymock` with a `__init__.py` in it. Other than that there are these 3 files:

**foo.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
class Foo(object):
    def foo1(self):
        return 1
```

**goo.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from foo import Foo


class Goo(object):
    def goo1(self):
        f = Foo()
        return f.foo1()
```

**goo_test.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from mock import patch, Mock
from nose.tools import assert_equal

from goo import Goo


class TestGoo(object):
    def setup(self):
        self.goo = Goo()

    @patch('pymock.foo.Foo', autospec=True)
    def test_goo1(self, foo1_mock):
        foo_instance = Mock()
        foo1_mock.return_value = foo_instance
        foo_instance.foo1.return_value = 11
        assert_equal(11, self.goo.goo1())
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to patch the *name* that `goo` is using.

```
@patch('pymock.goo.Foo', autospec=True)
```

Comment: Doesn't seem right. Anyway I tried - got `ImportError: No module named goo`

Comment: I wasn't sure if it needed the `pymock` as `well.

Comment: Ok with `pymock` it works. Thanks! Can you explain why this is the syntax?

Comment: `mock.patch` replaces the object that a name refers to, and `pymock.foo.Foo` is the name that your *test module* uses to access that function. Python has no true global variables; the `goo` module has its own reference to `foo.Foo` that its functions use, so *that* is the name you need to patch.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Problem is in my real case the class I am attempting to patch isn't from the same package as the class I am testing. What do I do in such a case?

Comment: Oh my jesus I was stuck on this for a day and this clicked it for me - don't patch the source of the method:  `@patch('djang.some.lib.get_template')` - patch where it's being used `@patch('my_project.email.get_template')`. Game changer.

Comment: @chepner, your third comment should be part of the answer, imo.  It does a great job at explaining why the answer is correct, as it applies to methods as well.

Answer (score 15):

Basically it's how you import functions/classes. In `goo.py` you've imported `Foo` directly. So `goo.py` has it's own reference to `Foo`, so your patch will have to be:
`@patch('pymock.goo.Foo', autospec=True)`

But if `goo.py` looked like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import foo


class Goo(object):
    def goo1(self):
        f = foo.Foo()
        return f.foo1()
```

the patch in your question would work since `goo.py` doesn't have a direct reference to `Foo`

Comment: Fantastic explanation of the why, @cberenik.  You helped me out of a pinch here, so thanks.